# Add or highlight a single points on a jQuery flot graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, graphing

I've already drawn a flot graph using some data:

```
    var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
    [{
        data: data,
    }], {
        series: {
            points: {
                show: true
            }
        },
        grid: {
            hoverable: true,
        }
    });
```

Now I'd like to highlight a *single* point on the graph, when a user hovers over an item elsewhere on the page.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455166/plot-a-new-series-on-an-already-rendered-jquery-flot-graph), which explains how to totally redraw the series from scratch, but is there a way to highlight a single point?

Or add a new point in a different colour, which would have the effect of a highlight?

NB: when the user hovers over the relevant item elsewhere on the page, I will have the x and y coordinates of the related point, but not the pixel coordinates on the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) provides the following methods:

> The Plot object returned from the plot function has some methods you
>   can call:
>
> - highlight(series, datapoint)
>
>   Highlight a specific datapoint in the data series. You can either
>     specify the actual objects, e.g. if you got them from a
>     "plotclick" event, or you can specify the indices, e.g.
>     highlight(1, 3) to highlight the fourth point in the second series
>     (remember, zero-based indexing).
> - unhighlight(series, datapoint) or unhighlight()
>
>   Remove the highlighting of the point, same parameters as
>     highlight.
>
>   If you call unhighlight with no parameters, e.g. as
>     plot.unhighlight(), all current highlights are removed.