# How can I add a new, single point to a flot graph?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, graphing

I'm working with data set where observations are sequentially obtained. New data points need to be placed on a flot graph, one at a time. This is **not** a case where (unlike this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716631/add-or-highlight-a-single-points-on-a-jquery-flot-graph)) I can simply highlight an existing point; I need to add a new point.

I know how to add a new point to the data series with .setData() and then redraw the graph with .draw(); however, when I have thousands of points, this slows things down tremendously, because I then have to redraw the graph completely several times a second.

So - is there any way of simply adding a point to the plot? Or, if I can't use flot for this, does anyone have any suggestions for javascript libraries that would let me create a plot and add points sequentially?

Answer (score 3):

Flot does not support redrawing individual series. If you update it expects to redraw the whole plot.  Both [jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html#jqPlot.drawSeries) and [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series-object) (addPoint method) support this.  HighCharts is a little more hands off with this, you add a point, it'll redraw/rescale what is needed.  Adding a single point can be potentially cause a lot of redrawing if it changes the plot scale (axis renderer, etc...)

**EDITS**

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/JrCXt/2/).  You'll have to cache the jqPlot files in your browser since they do not allow hotlinking.

```
someData = [[[]]];

someChart = $.jqplot('chart1', someData, {
    axes: {
        xaxis: {max:10,min:0},
        yaxis: {max:10,min:0}
    }
});

$('#target').click(function() {
  seriesObj = someChart.series[0];
  seriesObj.data.push([Math.random() * 10, Math.random() * 10]);
  someChart.drawSeries({},0);
});
```

Re-reading the docs you are correct that Highcharts redraws the whole plot.  I thought it was more refined than that.

Comment: Can you give some example code for jqPlot? The way I read the help page you posted, I have to add a series (that contains one point), then redraw only that series. However, I can't get this to work.

Comment: It appears that HighCharts' addPoint method redraws the whole chart. The reason I don't want to use flot is because it redraws the chart, so addPoint isn't helpful.

Comment: In your new example code, you add a point to a series, then redraw the entire series. I just want to add a point to the plot, without drawing anything except that point. I'd think that someChart.series.push({data: x}), then someChart.drawSeries() on the new series index, would work, but it doesn't. I'm stuck using HTML canvas now.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Mark! BTW, the jsfiddle is not working anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The best I've found to do this is by accessing the canvas itself and drawing to it directly, like this:

```
// Get the axis, so that we can figure out what canvas coordinates
// correspond to our plot coordinates
xAxis = plot.getXAxes()[0];
yAxis = plot.getYAxes()[0];
// determine how much space flot left on the edges of the graphs
offset = plot.getPlotOffset();

// get the context, so that we can draw on the canvas           
ctx = plot.getCanvas().getContext("2d");
// Convert our coordinates to canvas coordinates
x1 = xAxis.p2c(plotX) + offset.left;
y1 = yAxis.p2c(plotY) + offset.top;

// draw a translucent, red rectangle        
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(200,0,0,.1)";  
ctx.fillRect (x1, y1, 5, 5);
```

Of course, this will not allow you any access to the points as part of a series, but if you need to simply add lots of points to a plot without redrawing the entire plot, this is one way to do it.